# Why does the iterator in a JavaScript for loop not need a semicolon?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious why when making a for loop in JavaScript a ; is not necessary after the i++ statement? It tripped me up. It actually doesn't even work if you include a semicolon after the iterator statement.

e.g.

```
    for(var x=1; x<100; x++){

        document.write(x);
    }
```

Comment: best read official doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: because the spec says so. it has only three parts in the header.

Comment: `;` is there to unambiguously terminate a statement. The closing `)` already serves that purpose. An added `;` would be redundant noise.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While tokenizing the code for compiling, the JS-parser usually knows where statements start and end due to [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion).

In the case of a [for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) however, semicolons are interpreted as a separator of statements. For-Loops accept up to three "parameters". If you put in a semicolon, a fourth one will be expected and it will throw an error.

The *final-expression*-statement of a for-loop is terminated by `)`.

This control-structure behaves similar to [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), [C](http://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-for-loop/), [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [C++](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm)

<sub>thanks to @Antoniu Livadariu for mentioning this in the comments</sub>

**Further Information**

- [MDN - Lexical Grammar](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar)
- [MDN - The "for" Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [thejameskyle's super tiny compiler](https://github.com/thejameskyle/the-super-tiny-compiler/blob/master/the-super-tiny-compiler.js)

Comment: I think it's worth(ish) mentioning that this is not just a Javascript thing (from the wording of the question it seems like only javascript does this). AFAIK the most popular programming languages like C, C++, PHP and Java all behave like this. There are a few exceptions like Python or Ruby that follow a completely different logic though.

Comment: @AntoniuLivadariu could you provide any links/docs that explain this further? I'm not too familliar with C/C++/Java but I wouldn't mind mentioning that in my answer

Comment: I come from a Python background which is definitely why it feels weird to me.

Comment: Haha sorry I told myself "I will reply as soon as I get home" for the past 2 days but always forgot to! Here's the list: [php](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), [c](http://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-for-loop/), [c++](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm) and [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). Notice that in php you can pass multiple expressions separated by a comma, for example you could do something like `for($i=0;$i<666;echo $i, $i++)` or `for($i=0;$i<666;$i++,echo $i)` depending on when you want to echo `$i`